# Ubuntu 23.04 don't take the Azure AD roles

Tags: 23.04, azure

I have some machines joined to a Azure AD service, all works great except that the roles in Azure AD don't apply in Ubuntu machines (all are Ubuntu 23.04).
Exists any method that i can apply to solve this issue?
I undertand that roles in Azure are specific for Windows systems, I don't find anything in the web that can solve this problem.
Thanks for your time